# Access func and variables of UIViewController in other UiViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My app has navigational control i have 2 UIViewController. viewCon1 is initial view controller.

I then Pushed the **viewCon2** in navigational control. Now i want to access variables and func of **viewCon1** in **viewCon2** without static logic.

I used static func logic to get Self of viewCon1 i.e. WK_DshBrd

```
let dashBoardObj = WK_DshBrd.getDasBoardObject() as! WK_DshBrd
            dashBoardObj.unReadMsgsCaseArr?.append(caseNo)
```

But i get following error on runtime

```
    Could not cast value of type 'Watch_Extension.WK_DshBrd' (0x7f1e0) to 'Watch_Extension.WK_DshBrd' (0x7ed78).
```

How can i cast it or achieve required functioanlity in alternative way?

Comment: I got a better answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820903/get-wkinterfacecontroller-reference-while-pushing-interfacecontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepareForSegue method in your first controller. There you can retrieve second view controller like this:

```
let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
controller.data = "test" //PASS DATA HERE
```

Eventually you can even pass reference to first view controller here, but it's not recommended.

edit:

As you're using watchkit you can pass data in context variable. Check you this tutorial: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/52810/how-do-i-pass-data-between-screens-in-my-apple-watch-apps/

Comment: I cannot use Segue, my requirement is i need to push viewcontroller later. Not through Segue

Comment: So how are you switching to the second view controller. If you are using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier you can also pass data here.

Comment: I am developing in WatchKit and using pushControllerWithName("ViewCon2",context:nil) to push InterfaceController

Comment: Hmm I'm not familiar with WatchKit. Also you can try accessing initial view controller (if it's the one you need) using self.window.rootViewController property. Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: Yes i am using a storyboard

Comment: check you my edited answer

Comment: I am using same thing for passing data, the thing is i have to pass data later on not while pushing controller.

Comment: You can give your view controller as context then.