# Get WKInterfaceController reference while pushing interfaceController

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a Dashboard Controller in Apple watch and I am navigating to next **WKInterfaceController**  without using **Segue**.

```
pushControllerWithName("Messages_Detail",context: ["Data": messageDetailData])
```

Now I need to pass data from **Dashboard** to **Messages_Detail** later on after it has been loaded. I don't have any reference of it in Dashboard. How can I pass data to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a regular task of passing data between controllers and it is not a Watch-specific task generally speaking. Actually you need to send data back (with sending data forward you're already OK). I see 2 ways to solve your task depending on the current implementation:

1. Use the `Messages_Detail` controller as a delegate of the `Dashboard` one. You also should define some protocol that will describe which methods of the `Messages_Detail` are available to call in a delegate context.
2. Use `NSNotificationCenter` or any other implementation of a Pub/Sub pattern to provide communication of different parts of your app. In this case your `Dashboard` will post notifications which the `Messages_Detail` controller will observe.

Comment: I tried using first approach and i verify it is working ok thanks alot